# How do I run parallel jobs in python3 with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Assuming, that I have a class like that:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        run_some_long_time_function()
```

How can I create many instances of this class in parallel using asyncio in python 3.4.1?

Comment: related: [get output from *bash* commands concurrently using `asyncio`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asyncio event loop is single threaded, so nothing running on the event loop will run in parallel. You can however spawn a thread and wait for it to finish. The default executor should create a thread for you:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: MyClass()))
asyncio.async(loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: MyClass()))
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to go with multiprocessing.