# ProactorEventLoop - ValueError: loop argument must agree with Future

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using this asynchronous project (called `Broker` - [see git](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker)) with the following code:

```
   proxies = asyncio.Queue()
   broker = Broker(proxies)
   tasks = asyncio.gather(broker.find(types = ['HTTPS'], strict = True, limit = 10),
                               self.storeProxies(proxies))
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

where `self.storeProxies` is an async function that contains

```
while True:
    proxy = await proxies.get()
    if proxy is None: break
    self.proxies['http://{0}:{1}'.format(proxy.host, proxy.port)] = 1
```

However, I do not think that it is related to the `Broker` part (not sure of course).

Everytime I run this code, after a quite random number of successes, it fails with `[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`. I then tried to do some research and ended up at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643127/10938025). But when trying with this code, I get this error:

`ValueError: loop argument must agree with Future`

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Details that might be useful:

OS: Windows 10 (version 1809)
Python version: 3.7.1

Based on the answer from Mikhail Gerasimov

```
async def storeProxies(self, proxies):
    logger.info("IN IT!")
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        self.proxies['http://{0}:{1}'.format(proxy.host, proxy.port)] = 1

async def getfetching(self, amount):
    from proxybroker import Broker

    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    return await asyncio.gather(
        broker.find(
            types = ['HTTP', 'HTTPS'],
            strict = True,
            limit = 10
        ),
        self.storeProxies(proxies)
    )
def fetchProxies(self, amount):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    else:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(self.getfetching(amount))
    logger.info("FETCHING COMPLETE!!!!!!")
    logger.info('Proxies: {}'.format(self.proxies))
```

where `fetchProxies` is called at certain intervals from another place. This works perfectly the first time, but then "fails" with the warnings:

```
2019-04-06 21:04:21 [py.warnings] WARNING: d:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\proxybroker\providers.py:78: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
  headers=get_headers(), cookies=self._cookies, loop=self._loop

2019-04-06 21:04:21 [py.warnings] WARNING: d:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py:730: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
  loop=loop)

2019-04-06 21:04:21 [py.warnings] WARNING: d:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\cookiejar.py:55: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
  super().__init__(loop=loop)
```

followed by a behavior that seems like an infinite loop (hard stuck outputting nothing). Noteworthy, this also happened to me in the example from Gerasimov (in the comments) when importing `Broker` globally. Finally, I am starting to see the light of the tunnel.

Comment: Try calling `set_event_loop` before first importing Broker.

Comment: @user4815162342 Please see my update :))

Comment: This is still not before *importing* `Btoker`. To be sure, move the code to immediately after `import asyncio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this part:

```
proxies = asyncio.Queue()

# ...

loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

`asyncio.Queue()` when created is bound to current event loop (default event loop or one been set to current with [asyncio.set_event_loop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.set_event_loop)). Usually only loop object is bound to can manage it. If you change current loop, you should recreate object. Same is true for many other `asyncio` objects.

To make sure each object is bound to new event loop, it's better to create `asyncio`-related objects already after you set and ran new event loop. It'll look like this:

```
async def main():
    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    return await asyncio.gather(
        broker.find(
            types = ['HTTPS'], 
            strict = True, 
            limit = amount
        ),
        self.storeProxies(proxies)
    )


if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Sometimes (rarely) you'll have to place some imports inside `main()` either.

---

### Upd:

Problem happens because you change event loop between `fetchProxies` calls, but `Broker` imported only once (Python caches imported modules).

[Reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/1113207) `Broker` didn't work for me thus I couldn't find a better way than to reuse event loop you set once.

Replace this code

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

with this

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if not isinstance(loop, asyncio.SelectorEventLoop):
        loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop() # for subprocess' pipes on Windows
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

**P.S.**

BTW you don't have to do this in the first place:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Windows already use `SelectorEventLoop` as default and it **doesn't support pipes** ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#windows)).

Comment: Wow thank you so much for that answer! It does indeed seem to change the behavior but not I get a lot of ```File "d:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 505, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError```

Comment: @FacPam it's due to `ProactorEventLoop` you set. Take a look at [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#windows): "add_reader() and add_writer() are not supported". I'm afraid you'll have to continue use default `SelectorEventLoop`.

Comment: @FacPam there're chances `ProxyBroker` creators didn't test it on Windows. It makes scene to post an [issue](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/issues) there.

Comment: Om my gosh it works! You are a true savior. So now I just have a few questions that I hope you will answer: 1) The linked answer in the OP suggested to use `ProactorEventLoop`, so why does this also work with `SelectorEventLoop`? 2) Sometimes, at the line `proxy = await proxies.get()` (at least that is what the stack trace claims), I get ```File "d:\users\nichlasdesktop\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 469, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed``` - why?

Comment: Oh no, actually, now there are no proxies being stored (might have something to do with the error on the line in `storeProxies`) - `self.proxies` never contains any elements. Please let me steal just a little more of your time :))

Comment: @FacPam I've just created and ran [this example](https://pastebin.com/DYQuCZ2i) on Windows and it works fine. I'll need fully reproducible example of your code that doesn't work, otherwise I can't guess where problem is.

Comment: @FacPam [here's little example](https://pastebin.com/a1dSm3WT) that stores proxies in variable instead of printing them one by one immediately.

Comment: I really appreciate that you will do you that to help me! I see what you mean - the examples also work on my Windows pc. Let me play with it for some time and then get back to you :)

Comment: @FacPam true. `proxybroker` creates something `asyncio`-related on import stage. It's not a usual thing, but can be avoided placing import after event loop is running - [example](https://pastebin.com/7TvpTTmn)

Comment: Marvelous. Let me try something  then. I'll be back in a moment

Comment: Great, I have now done some tests. I have now updated the OP to show my current code based on your amazing inputs. However, this works perfectly the first time it is run, but then `fetchProxies` is called again after a few seconds and I get warnings followed by a behavior that acts like an infinite loop. Please take a look at my updated OP.

Comment: Perfect. Now one FINAL problem: Because that Proactor is not used (I think), the first problem mentioned in the OP reoccurs: `[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`. This error was the reason why I ended up at [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642695/asyncio-error-an-operation-was-attempted-on-something-that-is-not-a-socket/28643127#28643127). It's quite unfortunate that one fix for one problem causes another problem.

Comment: Is it possible to fix if usage of `ProactorEventLoop` causes `NotImplemented` and this is fixed by not using `SelectorEventLoop` which then causes `OSError: [WinError 10038]` for which the fix is to not use `ProactorEventLoop` (based on the linked answer) and so it loops...

Comment: @FacPam no, I think code you use can't work `ProactorEventLoop`. If you need both `Broker` and pipes simultaneously, you should run your code on another OS of find relevant third-party event loop implementation for Windows (I don't know any).

Comment: Good. Thank you SOOOO much! Only 0.01% of the SO users are as kind as you, even though you think the answers may be obvious. God bless you