# Is it possible to parallelize load to Oracle using Python/co-routines?

Tags: python, oracle, coroutine

I used `threading` module to open multiple `sqlloader` sessions and it worked fine.
Having troubles achieving same degree of parallelism using `asyncio` module (coroutines).

This code always loads sequentially in Python 3.5:

```
import asyncio

async def load_data(filename):

        loadConf=('sqlldr SKIP=%s %s userid=%s DATA=%s control=%s LOG=%s.log BAD=%s.bad DISCARD=/dev/null'  % (...)).split(' ')

        p = Popen(loadConf, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=False, env=os.environ)
        output, err =  p.communicate(pwd.encode())  
        status=p.wait()

async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([load_data(file1),load_data(file2)])


if __name__ == "__main__":  
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you have to use [asyncio.create_subprocess_shell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#create-a-subprocess-high-level-api-using-process) instead of `subprocess.Popen` since the latter doesn't know anything about the event loop and simply blocks inside your `load_data` until complete.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020599/asynchronously-receive-output-from-long-running-shell-commands-with-asyncio-pyt/34027086#34027086) is a relevant example.