# Python process pipes with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-2.7, pipe, subprocess

Here is a test file:

```
gunzip -c file_1.gz
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I am executing bash commands this way:

```
cmd = "gunzip -c file_1.gz | grep 3"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True))
Line 3
```

I need to run this command on several files in parallel, then join the processes. SO it seems I have to use `subprocess.Popen().communicate()`. However `Popen` won't recognize the pipe correctly and will feed it to the first command, gunzip in my case:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd.split()).communicate())
gunzip: can't stat: | (|.gz): No such file or directory
gunzip: can't stat: grep (grep.gz): No such file or directory
gunzip: can't stat: 8 (8.gz): No such file or directory
```

I would like to keep the whole command and to avoid separating it this way:

```
gunzip = subprocess.Popen('gunzip -c file_1.gz'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen('grep 3'.split(), stdin=gunzip.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
gunzip.stdout.close()
output = grep.communicate()[0]
gunzip.wait()
```

Is there a way to not separate the commands and process the pipe correctly?

Comment: What does "join the processes" mean? Do you want to capture the output of several processes running concurrently? Here's [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279). Unrelated: your code is probably IO bound i.e., there might be no point to read the files in parallel unless they are in memory already.

Comment: Sorry for delay.. By joining the processes I mean  waiting until all the grep are finished on each file. Your answer you are referring to is noteworthy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the `grep 3` command you need the output from the previous command, so there is no way to run this successfully in a single command with subprocess.Popen.

If you always want to run `grep 3` for all the files, you could just join the results of all the `gunzip -c file_x.gz` and then run the grep command only once on the entire list.

```
subprocess.Popen('gunzip -c file_1.gz'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen('gunzip -c file_2.gz'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
grep = subprocess.Popen('grep 3'.split(), stdin=all_gunzip_stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```