# Run multiple lines of cmd command using python

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I am trying to run to cmd code using python.

```
p = 'calcifer --config="C:\\Users\\yilin.chen\\Desktop\\pythonminingstuff\\calcifer\\calcifer\\pipelines\\run_config.yaml"'
subprocess.call('cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Olympus\\Vanta\\bin', shell = True)
subprocess.call(p, shell = True)
```

And later I found that, these two line of code should be ran together. So I tried

```
commands = """ SET foo=1 | SET foo=2 | echo %foo% """
b = subprocess.check_output(commands, shell=True)
print(b.decode('ascii'))
```

Which is posted here as a guide https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2013-January/093474.html
But it doesn't work for me. The code above only executes the lasty line which prints a %foo%.If I copy and paste the orirginal code, it only prints 'hello'.

Any thoughts? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I presume you are assuming that the `|` character is a command separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the '&&' operator.
For your example:

```
p = 'calcifer --config="C:\\Users\\yilin.chen\\Desktop\\pythonminingstuff\\calcifer\\calcifer\\pipelines\\run_config.yaml"'
subprocess.call('cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Olympus\\Vanta\\bin && ' + p, shell = True)
subprocess.call(p, shell = True)
```

You can also use os.system(command) to do the exact same thing:

```
import os
p = 'calcifer --config="C:\\Users\\yilin.chen\\Desktop\\pythonminingstuff\\calcifer\\calcifer\\pipelines\\run_config.yaml"'
os.system('cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Olympus\\Vanta\\bin && ' + p)
```

You can read more about it [**here**](https://datatofish.com/command-prompt-python/).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the first command you are trying to execute is to `cd` into a directory, which can be achieved by setting the `cwd` parameter in [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

To give you a little example, I copied the `echo` binary to `/Users/Samuel/tmp/eecchhoo`. If I try to go in the directory, then call the binary in two subprocess calls, I will have a failure, as you described:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('cd /Users/Samuel/tmp', shell=True)
0
>>> subprocess.call('./eecchhoo helloworld', shell=True)
/bin/sh: ./eecchhoo: No such file or directory
127
```

However I can make the call succeed by setting the `cwd` parameter to the value I want:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('./eecchhoo helloworld', shell=True, cwd='/Users/Samuel/tmp')
helloworld
0
```

If you need to run other commands (not only to change the working directory), you can refer to this answer: [Python: execute cat subprocess in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611396/python-execute-cat-subprocess-in-parallel/23616229#23616229).

Comment: It's amazing. But if I am going to do two 'echo', what should I do?

Comment: @ChenLin You can use `subprocess.call` like you did, but you need to separate the different commands correctly. On my platform (Mac OS), I can use `&&` ("and" operator) or `;` ("or" operator):
`subprocess.call('echo hello && echo world', shell=True)` and
`subprocess.call('echo hello ; echo world', shell=True)` both work.

Comment: I tried and it worked, thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate 
 it.