# How to run two Python scripts at the same time on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run multiple scripts to maintain the running speed.

I'm using two scripts that need each other to work, so I want another Python script like setup.py to run them:

```
import os
os.system('python script1.py && python script2.py')
```

But that doesn't work at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: execute cat subprocess in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611396/python-execute-cat-subprocess-in-parallel)

Comment: Your use case isn't very well defined. If `script2.py` depends on `script1.py`, the you cannot run them in parallel. (Or, at least not completely.) Is this the case or do you want to run both scripts together multiple times in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use multithreading : [Python - Multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

You will be able to run different python scripts in different threads.

That will allow you to execute them in the same time.

If your script doesnt require a lot of layers of data to process, then you can keep using your processor.

Otherwise you can use your GPU. For example cuda for NVIDIA GPU : [See cuda here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone)